# how can I rerender class error message in zend_form?

Tags: php, zend-form, rerender

Default error message in Zend_Form like this :

```
<ul class="errors">
    <li>Please enter your email !</li>
</ul>
```

I want to rerender like this :

```
<div class="errors">Please enter your email !</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Iam not giving detail ans but it will help you definitly....try like this in your form helper

```
// Email
$email = $this->createElement('text', 'email');
$email->setRequired(true)
->setLabel('Email *')
->addFilters(array('StringTrim'))
->setAttribs(array('class' => 'input-text'))
->addValidator('EmailAddress')
->addValidator('NotEmpty', true)
->clearDecorators()
->addDecorator('Label', array('escape' => false))
->addDecorator('ViewHelper')
->addDecorator('Errors')
->addDecorator(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'),
  array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'group'));
$email->getValidator('EmailAddress')
    ->setMessage('invalid email', 'emailAddressInvalidFormat');
$email->getValidator('NotEmpty')
    ->setMessage('enter email', 'isEmpty');
```

This is for your email validation custome error message in div's

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to pass the relevant `elementStart`, `elementEnd` and `elementSeparator` options to the `Errors` decorator view helper. For example

```
$element->addDecorator('Errors', array(
    'elementStart'     => '<div%s>',
    'elementSeparator' => '<br>',
    'elementEnd'       => '</div>'
));
```

You haven't said how you want to separator multiple error messages. I've assumed a line break using `<br>` above.

Comment: Can I use directly in Zend_Form ?